# Task scheduler runs a task immediately after logon even when delay is set

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I create a task to run 5 minutes after login and automatically repeat every 5 minutes. But each time I log in, the task will run immediately without delay. Is this due to the repeat settings?

The trigger of my task is:

```
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT5M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <UserId>My-User-Id</UserId>
      <Delay>PT5M</Delay>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
```

The other settings of my task are:

```
<Settings>
<MultipleInstancesPolicy>Queue</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
<DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
<StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
<AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
<StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
<RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
<IdleSettings>
  <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
  <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
</IdleSettings>
<AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
<Hidden>false</Hidden>
<RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
<WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
<ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
<Priority>7</Priority>
```